# SQL change over time query

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have created 2 tables. one table has 4 fields. a unique name, a date and 3 figures. The second table contains the same fields but records the output of a merge function. therefore has a date at which time the update or insert function happened. what I want to do is retrieve a sum of either the difference between 2 days or alternatively the totals of the 2 days to work out how much the value has changed over the day. The merge function only updates if a value has changed or it needs to insert a new value.

so far I have this

```
select sum(Change_Table_1.Disk_Space) as total,
Change_Table_1.Date_Updated

from VM_Info
left join Change_Table_1

on VM_Info.VM_Unique = Change_Table_1.VM_Unique
where VM_Info.Agency = 'test'
group by Change_Table_1.Date_Updated
```

but this would just return the sum of that days updated total rather than the difference between the two days. One answer to this question would be to to add all new records to the table but this would contain a number of duplicates. So in my head what I want it to do is loop over the current figures for the day then loop over the next day but also to include all values that haven't updated. sorry if I haven't explained this well. so what I want to achieve is to get some sort of change of the total over time. If its poor design im in a position to accept that also.

Any help is much appreciated.

maybe this would explain it better. show me total for day 1, if the value hasn't changed then show me the same value for day 2 if it has changed show me new value. and so on...

ok to further elaborate.

the Change_Table looks like

```
vm date created action value_Field1 value_field_2 Disk_Space


abc 14/10/2013 insert  5  5  30

def  14/10/2013 insert  5  5  75

abc  15/10/2013  update  5  5  75
```

---

so the out put I want is for the 14th the total for the last column is 105. On the 15th abc has changed from 30 to 75 but def hasn't changed but still neds to be included giving 150

so the output would look like

```
date       disk_Space

14/10/2013 105

15/10/2013 150
```

Comment: This is called rolling total or rolling delta value. "def" is not exist on 15th that means there is no change and so query should include previous value. best way to accomplish this is to generate missing rows as in they were exists. you will need new column RunningTotal by each value. and recursive CTE is the way to go for that calc. once you have running total value for any given date then it is just simple addition or subtraction for any two date. try it out, if needed will provide CTE query. rest is easy so you can do it.

Comment: thanks all for your help. I have decided to go with a running total table and work with a 1,7,14,28 day cycle. the main idea of this project was to get a...have you grown by x then every further change after that needs a charge. will read up on recursive CTE and get back if need be...

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? If not, can you provide a few rows of sample data, and an example of the desired result?

```
select 
  (VM_Info.Disk_Space - Change_Table_1.Disk_Space) as DiskSpaceChange,
  Change_Table_1.Date_Updated
from 
  VM_Info
  left join Change_Table_1 on VM_Info.VM_Unique = Change_Table_1.VM_Unique and VM_Info.Date = Change_Table_1.Date_Updated
where 
  VM_Info.Agency = 'test'
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholai. its not quite what I was looking for. have added examples of what I am after. the VM_info table holds no values and was only used so I could include a where clause on the change table.

Comment: Thank you for the sample records and result. As Anup commented, it will be easier to do the calculations if you populate rows for the dates that do not contain changes. Then you can use one of the examples from here to get the daily changes: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals